# Are there any alive CPU architectures with two stacks today?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

Is it simpler to prevent buffer overflows explorations with two stacks in general?
One stack for variables and passing arguments, the other for return addresses.

Or things like NX/XD-bits (on AMD/Intel x86) as non-executable stack do it better?

Comment: There are architectures that don't by default push the return address on the stack for "jump-and-link" type instructions, does that count? You could manually put it anywhere, including a "second stack"

Comment: is there a dead cpu architecture that does?

Comment: Certainly. Architectures using register-windows, such as SPARC or Itanium, spring to mind. More directly plenty of embedded 8-bit MCUs, such as the PIC18F family, also use dedicated return stacks.

Comment: Following up on what @harold said, you can do this on architectures that use push-return-address (x86) by having the data stack be somewhere else.  I actually don't know of any architecture where you *can't* do this, it just means throwing away a register name.

Comment: @dwelch the `6809` has two stack pointers, the hardware stack and the user stack, with `PSHS`, `PSHU`, `PULS` and `PULU` instructions. This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6809) says *"At the end of 2015, Rochester's MC6809 was into fabrication with expected production starting in July 2016."*

Comment: Very recently in the news: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTX2010

Comment: @HansPassant "boldly going forth..."?

Comment: Any CPU architecture can implement multiple stacks. You're not limited to using whatever special instructions or registers (if any) the CPU architectures has for implementing a stack. If you want multiple stacks on a ARM, x86 or 6502 CPU there's nothing stopping you.

Comment: Linux's `mmap(2)` has a `MAP_GROWSDOWN` flag, so you can efficiently allocate space for more custom stacks with `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_GROWSDOWN)`.  If you use a register-call ABI, not being able to `push` / `pop` doesn't hurt as much.  You just use stack space for saving/restoring registers, and for spilling local vars when you run out of registers.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Two stack pointers for User and Kernel mode is typical for many architectures: The two architectures used for today's PCs (x86 and ARM) have this feature. However the two stacks are never used in parallel.

Comment: @dwelch: There was one architecture that used two stacks in parallel: The 6502 when using high-level languages. Because the real stack was limited to 256 bytes a second stack (used for data) was emulated.

Comment: by those definitions many active cpu's do today.  Which ones did you examine thus far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Itanium has two stacks.  I believe one is for storing local variables (like arrays and stuff), while the other is for return addresses.  This way, you can't overwrite return addresses by overrunning a buffer.

[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050421-28/?p=35833](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050421-28/?p=35833/)

Answer (score 1):

## 32-bit ARM

Other than loading the program counter from a full descending stack using r13 as the stack pointer being treated as a return for branch prediction purposes the instruction set is neutral as to the register used as the stack pointer or the direction of stack growth. In assembly language "push" and "pop" are just alternative names for load and store instructions.

Thumb, the 16-bit wide instruction set, has a preferred stack pointer but still other registers can be used equally well.

The catch is multiple stacks requires multiple push/pop instructions.

## AVR

There are no instructions to add or subtract to the stack pointer, nor are there instructions to atomically set the stack pointer to a new value. Therefore creating a stack frame might involve:

1. Load low byte of stack pointer.
2. Load high byte of stack pointer.
3. Perform a 16-bit subtraction.
4. Save interrupt enable status.
5. Disable interrupts.
6. Store high byte of stack pointer.
7. Store low byte of stack pointer.
8. Restore interrupt enable status.

Failing to disable interrupts could result in 200 bytes of RAM being wasted which could result in stack overflow. (Some AVR models have 1024 bytes of RAM)

At least one C compiler uses a pair of general purpose registers as a data stack pointer which can be added to, or subtracted from atomically.

Comment: Some other RISC ISAs are totally neutral about stack pointers; e.g. MIPS doesn't have any push/pop instruction so you have to do it yourself for `$sp` or whatever other register you pick.  Even on ISAs like x86, you *could* manually modify another reg as a 2nd stack pointer; push/pop aren't magic.  The question is also whether the standard ABI on any of those platforms *does* use 2 stacks to separate return-address from automatic storage.