# Does the processor use more than one stack to separate the call stack from the expression/register stack?

Tags: cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, processor, stack-memory, stack-machine

I was reading some basic articles about memory manipulation by the processor, and I was confused as to how the processor handles what comes next.

The concept of the call stack is clear, but I was wondering if the expression stack/register stack (used to make the calculations) is the same stack, or even if the stack for the local variables of a subroutine (a function) in a program is the same call stack.

If anyone could explain to me how the processor operates regarding its stack(s), that'd help me a lot.

Comment: Isn't that more a decision to be made by the compiler (subject to calling conventions of OS and libraries)? The CPU will be fine with any memory arrangement, it just runs the instructions. I suppose you could write code without using any stack at all.

Comment: @Thilo: It would be silly to design an ABI that used a separate stack for scratch-space and parameter passing if the CPU didn't make it easy to do it efficiently.  In x86, for example, it would tie up another register (leaving only 6 of the 8 registers as "general purpose" in 32bit mode), and the small&efficient `push` / `pop` instructions only work with `rsp`.  So saving/restoring registers to a "manual" stack would take more code bytes (and more instructions, since you'd have to manually sub/add to `rbp` (the obvious choice for a 2nd stack pointer).

Comment: @PeterCordes: That is probably the answer Rafael was looking for: A CPU should have multiple sets of stack operations / registers to efficiently support multiple stacks (and x86 does not).

Comment: @PeterCordes so for different threads the processor uses the same stack but different pointers?

Comment: Hyperthreading (SMT: multiple logical CPUs on the same physical core) provides two totally separate contexts with their own architectural state.  OS task-switching between threads on a core fully replaces the architectural state of one thread with another.  Different threads always have their own stacks.  (They could all be carved out of the same large block of virtual memory in the process's address space, but if one thread writes its data over the stack space used by another thread to save/restore something, your program won't work.)

Comment: Itanium uses two stacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481141/are-there-any-alive-cpu-architectures-with-two-stacks-today/34642826#34642826

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the processors I've worked on have just used a single stack for these.

If you think about what the processor is doing, you only need a single stack.  During calculations you can use the same stack as the calling stack, as when the calculation is complete the stack will be 'clean' again.  Same for local variables, just before you go out of the scope of the local variables your stack will be clean allowing the call to return correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the stack just set the SS:SP segment and pointer registers (just save the current values)
The procedure call parameters and local variables takes place in the stack. And the dynamically created objects take place in the heap (DS:DI). The SS:SP register pair shifted by the right amount of bytes to reserve the needed memory on the procedure call. And on the return the SS:SP sets back to the pre call state.